# How to access each docker containers

Tags: mongodb, docker, meteor, docker-compose, dockerfile

In my docker-compose , I have 2 containers .

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    container_name: myApp
    image: myImage
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    networks:
      - myNetwork
    ports:
      - 9000:3000
    environment:
      ROOT_URL: http://192.168.0.122:9000
      MONGO_URL: mongodb://mongodb/pos-db
      PORT: 3000
      METEOR_SETTINGS: '{ "private": { "APP_NAME": "pos-db" } }'
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    networks:
      myNetwork:
        aliases:
          - mongodb
    ports:
      - 4001:27017
networks:
  myNetwork:
    external:
      name: myNetwork
```

I want to access from `container myApp` to `container mongodb` for backup data.
How to make this 2 containers access each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can put both services in the same network. When you put with same network you can reach both by container name.

Comment: They're not on the same network: in your question `app` is on `myNetwork` and `mongodb` is on `rabbitNetwork`.

Comment: Yes, sorry.I edited, how can I exec scrip from `app` to `mongodb` for backup data ?

Comment: Create your script in your App and put your mongo address to mongodb://mongodb-xxxxxxxxxxx.

Answer (score 0):

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    container_name: myApp
    image: myImage
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 9000:3000
    environment:
      ROOT_URL: http://192.168.0.122:9000
      MONGO_URL: mongodb://mongodb:4001/pos-db
      PORT: 3000
      METEOR_SETTINGS: '{ "private": { "APP_NAME": "pos-db" } }'
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 4001:27017
```

You don't need to specify the network. Docker containers in one docker compose file see themselves out of the box. You can access mongo from the app container on **mongodb://mongodb:4001**